# Times out by 1 hour in database

Tags: mysql, time, unix-timestamp

I've just taken over the development of a new system from a previous developer, and to be honest it's a mess.

All the diary items are ahead by 1 hour, the format they are saved in is 1355385600. The fields responsible for the time are start_time and end_time.

I need a way to bulk update all of the entries in the database and remove an hour from them.

Do you guys have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Cheers

**NOTE:** I should have mentioned that the default timezone is set correctly to 'Europe/London' and when you add a new diary entry the times are correct. What I need to do though, is find a way to bulk update all current entries in the database to go back by 1 hour. Is this possible?

Comment: have you checked time zone ? is it properly set ?

Comment: It's set correctly, used <?php echo date_default_timezone_get(); ?> to check. It is set to Europe/London.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the timezone.

For my sites, I set the timezone with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin')`, and when I insert a datetime in the database, I use `date('Y/m/d H:i:s')`.

For yours, instead of `date('Y/m/d H:i:s')`, it should be `strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'))`

Comment: I forgot to say, the app is built in CodeIgniter. If I set the timezone, it's not going to affect the current database entries is it?

Comment: No, it won't. You'd have to edit them manually, or use something such as updating them, with `mktime()`.

Comment: Is there a way to bulk update the times by putting them all back by 1 hour? A specific SQL statement or a script of some sort? Or is this simply infeasible.

Comment: Update it with something, such as `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($hour-1, $minute, $second, $day, $month, $year))`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this with SQL?

Comment: You'd just go through all the records, and update every time. Be aware that my way doesn't take account of records apparently being posted at 12:00AM GMT actually being posted on the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your fields and add one hour

```
UPDATE
    yourtable
SET
    start_time = start_time - 3600,
    end_time = end_time - 3600
WHERE
    start_time <= max time prior timezone fix
```

Edit: meant substract of course